# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject For Deserialize Data

Tags: c#, json, string

How to deserialize the following json string

```
{"key1":[{"name":"as", "age":"25"},{"name":"sd","age":"25"}],"qwed":"qwe"}
```

and

```
{"key1":{"name":"as", "age":"25"},"key2": {"name":"sd", "age":"25", "qwed":"qwe"}}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON - an array in JSON doesn't have keys and values directly in it.

Comment: is it weird I read @JonSkeet comment in his voice?

Comment: @JonSkeet is that both cases are incorrect?

Comment: @Jon Skeet can you help me with correct Json format

Comment: Well the question has now been edited to have valid JSON, but I'd expect you to have the JSON already - we shouldn't be guessing at what JSON you're trying to deserialize. Presumably some service is already providing you with that JSON.

Comment: @Mr.AF: I don't think it's a good idea to edit a post with *guesses* as to what the real JSON is that the OP is trying to deserialize.

Comment: @JonSkeet my apology.

Comment: @Jon Skeet how can i convert {"key1":{"name":"as", "age":"25"},"key2": {"name":"sd", "age":"25", "qwed":"qwe"}}

Comment: @Iceberg try to copy your json, and then use _Edit-Paste Special-Paste JSON as classes_ in visual studio, or share with us your attempts to solve your problem

Comment: Please edit your question to show the JSON you're really dealing with, as well as what you've tried. (There are lots of guides to JSON deserialization in .NET. You could start with https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm for example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First Json - {"key1":[{"name":"as", "age":"25"},{"name":"sd","age":"25"}],"qwed":"qwe"}

In my opinion, the json is not well formed. first value is array of `Data Object` and second one is having `String`. This is more of `string, object`. this can be Deserialized to `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
```

> Second Json - {"key1":{"name":"as", "age":"25"},"key2": {"name":"sd", "age":"25", "qwed":"qwe"}}

For the second json you can deserialize to `Dictionary<string, Data>` where the value of `qwed` may lead to `null` for the first value

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string qwed { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: there is an array of object and standalone property how does it possible to map it to dictionary ?

Comment: brought back down vote because Data model is wrong because qwed is property

Comment: First walking through is correct but bad practice because you are generating anonymous object that makes troubles in future because it need to be cast. in the data model may produce null qwed and again another problem.

Comment: @Mr.AF, have updated the post according to the json's in OP